# React Native with Expo - Keyboard compressing elements

Tags: javascript, react-native, keyboard, expo

On one screen there are 2 images in svg path format, 2 textinputs and a button. One image is at the top, and another at the bottom. Whenever I click on a textinput, the keyboard pushes the images and compresses all the elements. How could I solve it?

The project was created using Expo.

**index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Style from './style';

/* SVG Imports */
import PesqueiraOnline from '../../utils/pesqueira-online-path';
import Illustration from './svg-illustration';

export default class Login extends Component {    
    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <View style={Style.pesqueiraonline}>
                    <PesqueiraOnline />
                </View>

                <View style={Style.container}>
                    <Text style={Style.texto}>Faça login para começar a fazer suas compras!</Text>
                    <TextInput style={Style.loginInputs} placeholder="CPF" placeholderTextColor="#B4B4B4" />
                    <TextInput style={Style.loginInputs} placeholder="Senha" placeholderTextColor="#B4B4B4" />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={Style.loginButton}> 
                        <Text style={Style.textLoginButton}>ENTRAR</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View style={Style.illustration}>
                    <Illustration />
                </View>

            </>
        );
    }
}
```

**style.js**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default Style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    //backgroundColor: '#e1e1e1',
    marginBottom: 75
    },

    texto: {        
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
        color: '#333'
    },

    /* Pesqueria Online */
    pesqueiraonline: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: 50,
        width: '100%',
        height: undefined,

    },

    /* Illustration */
    illustration: {
      flex: 1,      
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginBottom: 35,      
      marginRight: 30
    },


    /* Login Inputs */
    loginInputs: {                    
        width: 267,
        height: 45,
        borderRadius: 20,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#BDBDBD',        
        marginTop: 15,
        paddingLeft: 15

    },

    /* Login Button */
    loginButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#6FCF97',
        borderRadius: 20,        
        width: 113, 
        height: 48,
        marginTop: 15,        
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    textLoginButton: {
      color: '#fff',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }

});
```

**A gif showing the problem:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you been able to solve this? i'm facing the same issue

Comment: Sorry for the delay to answer. Unfortunately I was unable to solve this problem.